# How to use a two class inventory program?

Tags: java

I have a question about my inventory program that needs a little tweaking to be functional. Essentially, I am asking the using to input the amount of a product that the individual wants to order, I want it to save in RAM, and then output the number of products and the total cost for the user. Here is my first constructor class "Item".

```
 import java.text.*;
 import java.util.*;
 import javax.swing.*;


public class Item
{
  public static final double SUBWOOFER_VALUE= 175.99; 
  public static final double TWEETER_VALUE= 34.49;    
  public int subOrder;
  public int tweetOrder;
  public double totPrice;
  public int subStock;
  public int tweetStock;

  public Item()
  {
      int subStock=1000;
      int tweetStock=3000;    

     double subPrice= (subOrder*SUBWOOFER_VALUE);
     double tweetPrice= (tweetOrder*TWEETER_VALUE);

  }


  public void addSubOrder(int newsubOrder)
  {
   subOrder=newsubOrder;
  }

  public int getSubOrder()
  {
   return subOrder;
  }

  public void addTweetOrder(int newtweetOrder)
  {
   tweetOrder= newtweetOrder;
  }

  public int getTweetOrder()
  {
   return tweetOrder;
  }

  public void newSubStock(int newSubStock)
  {
   subStock= newSubStock;
   newSubStock= (subStock)-(subOrder);
  }

  public int getsubStock()
  {
   return subStock;
  }

  public void newTweetStock(int newTweetStock)
  {
   tweetStock= newTweetStock;
   newTweetStock= (tweetStock)-(tweetOrder);
  }

  public int gettweetStock()
  {
   return tweetStock;
  }

  public void totPrice(double newTotPrice, double subPrice, double tweetPrice)
  {
   newTotPrice= (subPrice+tweetPrice)*(.065);
   totPrice= newTotPrice;

  }
  public double getTotPrice()
  {
   return totPrice;
  }



   public static void main (String[] args)
   { 
      Item Order= new Item();

   }//end main

}
```

And then here is my controller class, that controls the inputs and the outputs...

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.util.*;

public class Controller
{

   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
     Scanner myScan=new Scanner(System.in);
     Item Order= new Item();

 String question= "Would you like to make an order?";
 String question1= "Would you like to order Subwoofers?";
 String question2= "Would you like to order Tweeters?";
 String question3= "How many would you like to order?";
 String question4="Would you like to place another order?";
 String thank= "Thank you for your order,";

 System.out.println(question);
 String answer= myScan.nextLine();
 System.out.println(question1);

 while(!answer.equalsIgnoreCase("No"))
 {


  String subAns= myScan.nextLine();

  if(subAns.equals("Yes"))
  {
   System.out.println(question3);
   int subOrder= myScan.nextInt();      
  }

   System.out.println(question2);
   String tweetAns= myScan.nextLine();

   if(tweetAns.equals("Yes"))
   {
     System.out.println(question3);
     int tweetOrder= myScan.nextInt();
   }


  else//If subAns= no then proceed to ask about tweeters.
   {

     tweetAns= myScan.nextLine();

     if(tweetAns.equals("Yes"))//If tweeter answer = yes then proceed to ask for an amount
     {
       System.out.println(question3);
       int tweetOrder= myScan.nextInt();

     }

   }break;
 }//end while 

System.out.println(thank);
System.out.println("Your ordered: "+ Order.getSubOrder() + " Subwoofer's and "+ Order.getTweetOrder() + " Tweeter's");
System.out.println("Your total is:"+ Order.getTotPrice()); 







   }//end main


}//Two items
```

So when I input something and expect an output, I know get 0's in my output.

----jGRASP exec: java Controller

Would you like to make an order?
Yes
Would you like to order Subwoofers?
Yes
How many would you like to order?
9
Would you like to order Tweeters?
Yes
How many would you like to order?
4
Thank you for your order,
Your ordered: 0 Subwoofer's and 0 Tweeter's
Your total is:0.0

----jGRASP: operation complete.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you never call any of your methods to calculate update the state of `Item` (`totPrice()`) and you don't update the fields yourself ( `subStock` `tweetStock`) thus they are still their initial value because you never changed them.

On a side note it would make more sense for you to make a `subwoofer` and `tweeter` object of type Item in your controller to avoid having to double all your code in item

Also since java is pass by value, assigning to your functions arguments (such as`newSubStock= (subStock)-(subOrder);` in `newSubStock()`) are redundant and have no purpose

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why are you using swing.* import? You need to rectify your code a lot. You are using ignore case for 'NO' but not using the same for 'yes'. You have never used 'question4'. And also once you get the order in subOrder and tweetOrder, where are you using it? You need to call the methods of Item object in order to do the calculations.

Try adding "Order.addSubOrder(subOrder); & Order.addTweetOrder(tweetOrder);" after getting the orders.